# Apache localhost only on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apache, localhost, ubuntu-18.04

I want to run Apache on my desktop and only accept localhost connections. I am also using Ubuntu 18.04. I am hoping I can achieve this my modifying Apache's configuration file, I don't really want to use IPTABLES.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and edit the file *000-default.conf*:

```sh
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Then add the following two lines to the block `<Directory /var/www/html/>`:

```
Require host localhost
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```

It should look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
    # ... other configurations ...
    Require host localhost
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Save and exit the file then **restart the *apache2* service**:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```